# Why is my video playing limited to a couple seconds when i add it to VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCsPmzrwXG0 
AS you can see it is limited to the black line. Im sure theres a way to make it view the WHOLE of your video, but i dont know how and i cant find a tutorial to do it. thanks, Bye

Comment: In Matt's screenshot there is a preview button at #1. Is it checked?

Comment: Here is the fix which I have found in YouTube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h56EyYeaF24
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOWv.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOWv.jpg)

Answer (score 11):

I'd be willing to bet that you need to set the frame range. The length of your video is pretty close to 250 frames, which is the default.

Check out #2.

[image]

The length of the video is also controlled by frame RATE. Make sure this is set to the same frame rate as the original video.

Check out "Frame Rate" set to 24fps below.

[image]

Comment: Actually, I tried that. Didnt work.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the settings

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom left of the 3D window, click on the view icon and choose "Timeline".  At it's low edge can be found the frame range settings. it usually starts at 1, the next to the right being it's max.  It's probably set at the default 250 frames.

Change this to whatever the loaded video is in length.  If you're not sure, put in 1,000 and see what happens.  Re-select the 3D window (Bottom left icon) and choose "3D Window again), then ALT-A to make it play.

I struck this problem myself when first using Blender.  Hope this helps

PS: You can drag the 3D window down from it's top right (triangular hatch pattern) so you have 2 windows.  Set the bottom one to the Timeline view.  Leave the cursor in that and press the "HOME" key to adjust it to cover the current frame range.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing the same issue and as suggested I did check the frame rate, which unfortunately didn't work out.

But then I closed the current window and reopened Blender and this time instead of drag and drop (which I did before) I used the dropdown **add**, above the sequencer, and imported my **movie** from the options... You won't believe, somehow this solved the issue.

This does seem to be a bug coz I tried this so many times, if you drag and drop then the video *sometimes plays and sometimes not*. I have tried opening videos by using this 'add' dropdown and it works everytime.
(However if it doesn't play after drag and drop then just change the (AV) Sync option, from the playback menu at the bottom left of the sequencer, *to any of two except 'sync to audio'*. This somehow fixed the issue for me, I was only able to play the video in reverse when this option was selected, but after changing it there were no issues)

I am quite new at all this and I had installed Blender using snap on my Ubuntu 20.04. For some reason I am not facing the issue right now (I tested the drag and drop again and for 10/10 times it worked without any problem), but I was facing it 2 weeks ago.

Comment: this option does not work for me on blender 3.1.2, it still sticks with the original 250 frames even with Add > Movie

Answer (score 0):

Once you stretch out the content, you’ll need to input that number that’s on the project AFTER you stretch it if you need to. In frame range in the end box

Answer (score 0):

Add your video as a Background or Reference (In *Object Mode*, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, select Image, and in the open popup, turn off the filter to see videos). When video is added, click on the video in the Outliner (it might be collapsed under an Empty), and go to the Image submenu and change the value under Frames to something greater than the default value of 100.

[image: Screenshot of Blender Outliner and Image menu]